# Reversing a String with Recursion in Java

Tags: java, string, recursion, reverse

Here is some Java code to reverse a string recursively.

Could someone provide an explanation of how it works?

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
    if ((null == str) || (str.length() <= 1)) {
        return str;
    }
    return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}
```

I'm not understanding how this can possibly work.

Comment: It's homework, @DwB - I think it's a reasonable demonstration of recursion.

Comment: @DwB it has a homework tag, so they are probably using it to teach recursion.  Its one of the easiest ways to understand how recursion works the first time

Comment: It didn't have the homework tag when I added the comment.

Comment: @DwB Sorry DwB, you are right, I did not have a homework tag on it. This isn't necessarily for an real world application, it was just for me to understand what exactly is going on in this example of recursion.

Comment: I got asked this today and I think I was supposed to come up with what you wrote. What I did come up with was this http://pastebin.com/r4B3xEMe More code, but a reverses in half the calls.

Comment: @PeterTurner, were you asked to do it in Delphi or you chose that? Interesting language choice for such a question.

Comment: @david, I got asked it in an interview for a place where I'll be programming on java when I'd been programming Delphi for the last 8 years.

Comment: @PeterTurner, interesting, and how did that turn out for that particular question session? I assume the interviewer may not have been familiar with Delphi.

Comment: @DwB why its bad i got and interview main question about this but in c++ even i am a java developer .?

Comment: I have already answered the [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150131/java-recursively-reverse-an-array)

Comment: This will not reverse a String, because you can not reverse a String by arranging its char values in reverse order. UTF-16 does not work that way as an encoding of code points. And then there is the difficulty of diacritic modifier characters.

Comment: This could always be a challenge from Codewars.com or Leetcode.com, I would not just assume it is homework. Things like leetcode after a certain period of time being stuck, it is acceptable to look up an answer, at that point in time, one would want to get to where they can understand the answer and how and why it works.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The function takes the first character of a String - `str.charAt(0)` - puts it at the end and then calls itself - `reverse()` - on the remainder - `str.substring(1)`, adding these two things together to get its result - `reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0)`

When the passed in String is one character or less and so there will be no remainder left - when `str.length()  <= 1)` - it stops calling itself recursively and just returns the String passed in.

So it runs as follows:

```
reverse("Hello")
(reverse("ello")) + "H"
((reverse("llo")) + "e") + "H"
(((reverse("lo")) + "l") + "e") + "H"
((((reverse("o")) + "l") + "l") + "e") + "H"
(((("o") + "l") + "l") + "e") + "H"
"olleH"
```

Comment: I think that's one of the best answers I ever read on Stack Overflow. I didn't even need to read the 5 lines of explanation, just by checking your example I was able to figure it out how to recursively do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

You need to remember that you won't have just *one* call - you'll have *nested* calls. So when the "most highly nested" call returns immediately (when it finds just "o"), the next level up will take `str.charAt(0)` - where `str` is "lo" at that point. So that will return "ol".

Then the *next* level will receive "ol", execute `str.charAt(0)` for *its* value of `str` (which is "llo"), returning "oll" to the next level out.

Then the *next* level will receive the "oll" from its recursive call, execute `str.charAt(0)` for *its* value of `str` (which is "ello"), returning "olle" to the next level out.

Then the *final* level will receive the "oll" from its recursive call, execute `str.charAt(0)` for *its* value of `str` (which is "hello"), returning "olleh" to the original caller.

It may make sense to think of the stack as you go:

```
// Most deeply nested call first...
reverse("o") -> returns "o"
reverse("lo") -> adds 'l', returns "ol" 
reverse("llo") -> adds 'l', returns "oll" 
reverse("ello") -> adds 'e', returns "olle" 
reverse("hello") -> adds 'h', returns "olleh"
```

Comment: I think this is the correct simple explanation and not the one accepted because recursive call will be evaluated first and then "str.charAt(0)". it will be better understood by splitting the last line into two lines "String ab = reverse(str.substring(1)); return  ab + str.charAt(0);"

Answer (score 4):

Run it through a debugger. All will become clear.

Comment: "by far, the best answer"? So why did it get 0? And why do people keep saying to watch it run on such long strings? And under what circumstances does it terminate on "null==str"? Even a newly created String object does not do this. What is the length of a null String object, after all?

Answer (score 3):

Run the code below - it prints:

> Step 0: ello / H
>   Step 1: llo / e
>   Step 2: lo / l
>   Step 3: o / l
>   Step 3 returns: ol
>   Step 2 returns: oll
>   Step 1 returns: olle
>   Step 0 returns: olleH

Code:

```
public class Test {

    private static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        reverse("Hello");
    }

    public static String reverse(String str) {
        int localI = i++;
        if ((null == str) || (str.length()  <= 1)) {
            return str;
        }
        System.out.println("Step " + localI + ": " + str.substring(1) + " / " + str.charAt(0));
        String reversed = reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);

        System.out.println("Step " + localI + " returns: " + reversed);
        return reversed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because this is recursive your output at each step would be something like this:

1. "Hello" is entered. The method then calls itself with "ello" and will return the result + "H"
2. "ello" is entered.  The method calls itself with "llo" and will return the result + "e"
3. "llo" is entered.  The method calls itself with "lo" and will return the result + "l"
4. "lo" is entered.  The method calls itself with "o" and will return the result + "l"
5. "o" is entered.  The method will hit the if condition and return "o"

So now on to the results:

The total return value will give you the result of the recursive call's plus the first char

To the return from 5 will be: "o"

The return from 4 will be: "o" + "l"

The return from 3 will be: "ol" + "l"

The return from 2 will be: "oll" + "e"

The return from 1 will be: "olle" + "H"

This will give you the result of "olleH"

Answer (score 2):

Inline sample;

```
public static String strrev(String str) {
    return !str.equals("") ? strrev(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0) : str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the string Hello and run it through recursively.

So the first call will return:

```
return reverse(ello) + H
```

Second

```
return reverse(llo) + e
```

Which will eventually return `olleH`

Answer (score 0):

The call to the reverce(substring(1)) wil be performed before adding the charAt(0).
since the call are nested, the reverse on the substring will then be called before adding the ex-second character (the new first character since this is the substring)

reverse ("ello") + "H"                        = "olleH"
 --------^-------
         reverse ("llo") + "e"                 = "olle"
         ---------^-----
                 reverse ("lo") + "l"          = "oll"
                 --------^-----
                        reverse ("o") + "l"    = "ol"
                        ---------^----
                                  "o"          = "o"

Answer (score 0):

run the following and you'll see what's going on:

```
public class RS {

    public static String reverse(String str) {
        System.out.println("--- reverse --- " + str);
        if ((null == str) || (str.length() <= 1)) {
            return str;
        }
        return add(reverse(str.substring(1)), charAt(str));
    }

    public static char charAt(String s) {
        System.out.println("--- charAt --- " + s);
        return s.charAt(0);
    }

    public static String add(String s, char c) {
        System.out.println("--- add --- " + s + " - " + c);
        return s + c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("start");
        System.out.println("result: " + reverse("hello"));
        System.out.println("end");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution what I found.

```
public class Manager
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Sameer after reverse : " 
                         + Manager.reverse("Sameer"));
        System.out.println("Single Character a after reverse : " 
                         + Manager.reverse("a"));
        System.out.println("Null Value after reverse : "
                         + Manager.reverse(null));
        System.out.println("Rahul after reverse : "
                         + Manager.reverse("Rahul"));
    }

    public static String reverse(String args)
    {
        if(args == null || args.length() < 1 
                                || args.length() == 1)
        {
            return args;
        }
        else
        {
                return "" + 
                               args.charAt(args.length()-1) + 
                               reverse(args.substring(0, args.length()-1));                                  
        }
    }
}
```

Output:C:\Users\admin\Desktop>java Manager
Sameer after reverse : reemaS
Single Character a after reverse : a
Null Value after reverse : null
Rahul after reverse : luhaR

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReverseString{

private static  String reverse(String text, String reverseStr){
    if(text == null || text.length() == 0){
        return reverseStr;
    }
    return reverse(text.substring(1), text.charAt(0)+reverseStr);
}
public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println(reverse("hello", "")); //output is "olleh"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Another Solutions for reversing a String in Java.

Convert you string into a char array using .toCharArray() function.

```
public static char[] reverse(char in[], int inLength, char out[],
            int tractOut) {

        if (inLength >= 0) {
            out[tractOut] = in[inLength];
            reverse(in, inLength - 1, out, tractOut + 1);
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {
   public static void main (String[] args){
      String input = "hello";
      System.out.println(reverse(input));
    }

    private static String reverse(String input) {
        if(input.equals("") || input == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return input.substring(input.length()-1) + reverse(input.substring(0, input.length()-1));
} }
```

Here is a sample code snippet, this might help you. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringReverser
{
   static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static String getReverser(String in, int i)
   {
      if (i < 0)
         return "";
      else
         return in.charAt(i) + getReverser(in, i-1);
   }

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      int index = 0;

      System.out.println("Enter a String");
      String input = keyboard.nextLine();


      System.out.println(getReverser(input, input.length()-1));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there 2 thing in every recursion function :

1. There is always a **stop condition** which is :

   > if ((null == str) || (str.length() <= 1)) {
   >           return str;
   >       }
2. Recursion use the **stack** memory which use *LIFO* mechanism that's why the revert happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
`public class reverseString {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    String  brr= "momo";
    int n=brr.length()-1;
    
    string_Finder(brr,n);
     
}
 public static void string_Finder(String arr,int n) {
      
       if(n==0) {
           System.out.println(arr.charAt(0));
       }else {
           System.out.println(arr.charAt(n));
           
           string_Finder(arr,n-1);
       }
       
       }
```

}`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class recursion{
    public static void main (String []args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input: ");
    String input = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Reversed: ");
    System.out.println(reverseStringVariable(input));

    }public static String reverseStringVariable(String s) {
        String reverseStringVariable = "";

        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i != -1; i--) {
            reverseStringVariable += s.charAt(i);

        }

        return reverseStringVariable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
   return (str == null || str.length()==0) ? str : reverseString2(str.substring(1))+str.charAt(0);
}
```