# Recursion String in Java and removing characters

Tags: java, string, recursion, character

Here is what I have so far, but DrJava doesnt seem to compile it. It is supposed to print out "!olleH"..  and I keep getting these errors: cannot find symbol : class Sentence, cannot find symbol : method reverse(), cannot find symbol : method getText().

```
public class SentenceTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String greeting = new Sentence("Hello!");
      String.reverse();
      System.out.println(greeting.getText());
   }
}
```

I am also supposed to(once this is running) implement a recursive solution by removing the ﬁrst character, reversing a sentence consisting of the remaining text, and combining the two.

I am not asking for my homework to be done but better yet a barebones code because I really dont know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Where is that code from? Is that from your task description or not? There are *several* things wrong (apart from the missing parts). 1. you *define* a `String` but *assign it* a `Sentence` object. 2. you seem to try to call a static method `String.reverse` when you *probably* wanted to do something like `greeting.reverse()`.

Comment: The code i think was a barebones for what is supposed to be done. Basically I am just supposed to take a string(Hello!), reverse it, then print it out.. It should print out: (!olleH)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to recursively reverse a string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859562/whats-the-best-way-to-recursively-reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @user2092082: that code, as you posted it, can't work at all, no matter what other code you wrote. If that's in your problem description then it is broken (either intentionally or not). If it's *your interpretation* of the problem description, then that's a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `reverse()` method in `String` class. You can use a `StringBuilder` instead:

```
String greeting = "Hello!"
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(greeting);
greeting = sb.reverse().toString();
```

See [StringBuilder.reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29).

Also, I don't know what the `Sentence` class is, but you probably can't initialize a `String` with it.

Comment: That worked thankyou so much.. Is there any way you could intruct me on something such as: implementing a recursive solution by removing the ﬁrst character, reversing a sentence consisting of the remaining text, and then combining the two?

Comment: There are several questions about this already in SO. Just look at this one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723912/reversing-a-string-recursion-java