# JAVA: help fixing recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

I have to use recursion for this problem, I managed to make it work using loops pretty quickly but I'm a bit stuck on this. 
My current code is

```
public static String ReverseR(String n){
    String finalstring="";
    int i = 0;
    int len = n.length();
    while (i < len) {
        finalstring += (n.charAt(len -  1));
        ReverseR(n.substring(0, len - 1));
        i++;
    }
    return finalstring;
}
```

When I input any string, the resulting string is the correct length, but only uses the last letter. Ex: ReverseR("Hello") = ooooo
Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this link for help on recursion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526274/java-help-fixing-recursive-function

Comment: Use either a loop, or recursion.  Not both.

Answer (score 5):

Recursion is kind of like proof by induction.

1. Get rid of the while-loop
2. If you're inverting a 0-character string, that's easy: just return ""
3. if you're inverting a n-character string, invert [0..n-2] and prepend the last letter. Which you're already doing.

Comment: also "remember that Strings in java aren't mutable, you need to _return_ the modified string"

Answer (score 1):

change `n.charAt(len -  1))` to `n.charAt(len -  i))`

you are always in the same place with len -1 ;)

[EDIT]

```
while (i < len){
    finalstring += (n.charAt(len - 1 - i));
    ReverseR(n.substring(0, len - 1 - i));
    i++;
}
```

this will fix your code, however you have to choose between `while` or `ReverseR(...)`

Duplicate question, check this [Reversing a String with Recursion in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723912/reversing-a-string-recursion-java)

Comment: while this does solve the proble, it removes the need for the recursion :)  (which may be required for the OPs homework).

Comment: This will throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working solution

```
public static String reverse(final String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    final int length = s.length();
    if (length <= 1) {
        return s;
    } else {
        // s = start + lastChar
        final String start = s.substring(0, length - 1); 
        final char lastChar = s.charAt(length - 1);
        return lastChar + reverse(start);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive algorithm shouldn't require any loops, i.e. `while` and `for` loops.  Any looping constructs can essentially be implemented through recursion without ever touching a loop.  An example of basic recursive String reversal could be like this:

```
public static String reverseR(String n){
  if (n.length() <= 1) return n;
  return reverseR(n.substring(1))+n.charAt(0);
}
```

With this algorithm, you're basically saying:
return "the reverse of every letter but the first"+"the first letter"

A good thing to help with writing recursive algorithms is making a lot of assumptions.  Assume first that your reverse function works and then place it within itself wherever you want to reverse a portion of your string.  Just remember to add a base case and you'll be golden.  Languages like `Haskell` or `Prolog` will get you used to recursive algorithms since that is their main source of iteration.

Comment: duplicate code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723912/reversing-a-string-recursion-java

Comment: Ah, good find.  Looks like this is a pretty common way of doing this!