# Using recursion without truncating?

Tags: java, recursion

I can't understand this recursive method as the return method doesn't seem to add the charAt(0) method per run.

Suppose you were given a method that reverses a String (it is correct):

```
 public String reverseString(String s) {
        if (s.length() <= 1) 
             return s;

        return reverseString(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
    }
```

---

EDIT: I now understand:

- rs(Hello)
- rs(ello) + H
- (rs(llo) + e) + H
- ((rs(lo) + l) + e) + H
- (((rs(o) + l) + l) + e) + H
- o + l + l + e + H

Comment: Notice that you're only passing `s.substring(1)`, and not `s.substring(1) + s.charAt(0)` to the recursive invocation.

Comment: FYI this is a *horribly inefficient* way to reverse a string. It has to do a string concatenation (which constructs a new string object) at each level of the recursion. Using a `StringBuilder` would be much more efficient.

Comment: I found a duplicate (with same answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723912/reversing-a-string-recursion-java

Answer (score 2):

It is :

```
 rs(Hello)
 rs(ello) + H
 (rs(llo) + e) + H
 ((rs(lo) + l) + e) + H
 (((rs(o) + l) + l) + e) + H
 o + l + l + e + H
```

Comment: Is H stored in a buffer until the recursion reaches its base case?

Comment: Local variables are being stored on a stack. Read about [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)