# Program to reverse the words in a string

Tags: java, recursion

I have written a program to reverse the words in a string.
if i/p is "The dog is chasing"
then o/p should be "chasing is dog The"

```
public class String_reverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input= "The dog is chasing";

        String[] arr= input.split(" ");
        String reverse="";
        for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            reverse+= ((reverse.equals(""))?"":" ")+arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println(reverse);

    }

}
```

But I don't know how to write this program using recursion. When I tried searching in stackoverflow, I could find reversing a string; but not reversing the words in a string.

Comment: Just think about it in general terms first, not Java specifically. On any given recursive call, you have a current word, and a rest of the sentence. What would you do? Would you display the current word, then do the rest of the sentence? Or something else? Of course you need to be mindful of the case when you run out of words (or are on the last word).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reversing a String with Recursion in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723912/reversing-a-string-with-recursion-in-java)

Comment: No . It's not duplicate. In that question, they are reversing a string. Eg: Hello to olleH

Comment: @SethuramanSrinivasan It *is* the same thing, except you append the first word, not the first character, and with a space separator.

Comment: @Andreas How do you substring an array?

Comment: @YassinHajaj What array? You are substring'ing the text (`input`).

Comment: @Andreas But how do you the bound of the last word? I thought of array because OPs using split();

Comment: @YassinHajaj In a recursive method you wouldn't use `split()`, since the method signature would be `String reverseWords(String text)`.

Comment: Ok but this does not answer the question. How, in a String, do you know the bound of the last word?

Comment: @YassinHajaj Don't know what you mean by "bound of last word". You're at last word when there is only one word left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Recursive methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#In_computer_science) could seem a bit hard when beginning but try to do the following :

- Simplify the problem as much as possible to find yourself with the less complicated case to solve. (Here for example, you could use a sentence with two words).
- Begin with doing it on a paper, use [Pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) to help you dealing with the problem with the simplest language possible.
- Begin to code and do not forget an escape to your recursion.

---

### Solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = reverseSentence("This sentence will be reversed - I swear".split(" "));
    System.out.println(s);
}

public static String reverseSentence(String[] sentence){
    if (sentence.length <= 1){
        return sentence[0];
    }
    String[] newArray = new String[sentence.length-1];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < newArray.length ; i++){
        newArray[i] = sentence[i];
    }
    return sentence[sentence.length-1] + " " + reverseSentence(newArray);
}
```

Comment: A lot of overhead in array cloning, and requires caller to prepare the data by calling `split()`.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive method, using same logic as [linked "duplicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723912/reversing-a-string-with-recursion-in-java), without use of `split()`:

```
private static String reverseWords(String text) {
    int idx = text.indexOf(' ');
    return (idx == -1 ? text : reverseWords(text.substring(idx + 1)) + ' ' + text.substring(0, idx));
}
```

The logic is:

1. Take first char/word
2. If that is last char/word, return with it
3. Perform recursive call with remaining text (excluding word-separating space).
4. Append space (if doing word)
5. Append first char/word from step 1
6. Return result

As you can see, when applied to reversing text (characters) instead of words, it's *very* similar:

```
private static String reverseText(String text) {
    return (text.length() <= 1 ? text : reverseText(text.substring(1)) + text.charAt(0));
}
```

---

For people who like things spelled out, and dislike the ternary operator, here are the long versions, with extra braces and support for null values:

```
private static String reverseWords(String text) {
    if (text == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int idx = text.indexOf(' ');
    if (idx == -1) {
        return text;
    }
    return reverseWords(text.substring(idx + 1)) + ' ' + text.substring(0, idx);
}
private static String reverseText(String text) {
    if (text == null || text.length() <= 1) {
        return text;
    }
    return reverseText(text.substring(1)) + text.charAt(0);
}
```

Notice how the long version of `reverseText()` is exactly like the version in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample program which will do what you want recursively:

```
public class ReverseWords {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "This is a test";
        reverse(s);
    }

    private static void reverse(String s) {
        if(s == null) return;
        String words[] = s.split(" ", 2);
        if (words.length < 2) reverse(null);
        else reverse(words[1]);
        System.out.print(words[0] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following code.

```
  class ReverseString {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String myString = "The dog is chasing";

    reverse(myString);
}

public static String reverse(String myString) {
    int space = myString.indexOf(" ");
    if (space != -1) {
        reverse(myString.substring(space + 1, myString.length()));
    }
    if (space == -1) {
        System.out.println(myString.substring(0, myString.length()));
    } else {
        System.out.println(myString.substring(0, space));
    }
    return myString;
}
}
```